# Deleted directory doesn't appear at the bin and doesn't give the free space back

Tags: kubuntu, directory, disk-usage, delete

I'm using Kubuntu. My disk was full some days ago and the system requested me to delete files. 
I deleted a ~17GB directory, but it didn't appear at the bin and didn't released the space.

What could be happening? Thanks!

df -h

```
~$ df -h
S. fitxers      Mida En ús Lliure  %Ús Muntat a
/dev/sda1       145G  131G   6,4G  96% /
none            4,0K     0   4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            985M   12K   985M   1% /dev
tmpfs           201M  880K   200M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0   5,0M   0% /run/lock
none           1001M   84K  1001M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   16K   100M   1% /run/user
```

Comment: Can you please [click here](http://askubuntu.com/posts/360298/edit) and provide us the output of `df -h`?

Comment: There seems to be some free space there, what makes you think you didn't get the space back?

Comment: I deleted more things because what I deleted didn't give the space, of course :/

Answer (score 0):

A good program to visualize these types of things is the Disk Usage Analyzer.

Sometimes on drives a .Trash folder is created when these files get "moved" to the bin.

This will at least help you to figure out exactly where the space is going.